# how to text zoom effect in css

Tags: html, css

I want to zoom the text as like [this](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/OriginalHoverEffects/index6.html). but in this text opacity:0. I don't have to hide the text the text opacity:1 and i don't want box as like that only text would be zoom

I tried the following but without success:

```css
ul li {
  transform: scale(10);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
}

ul li:hover {
  transform: translateY(100px);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Text effect</li>
  <li>Text effect</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: *but in this text opacity:0. I don't have to hide the text* - okay, so can you not just remove `opacity:0`?

Comment: Not hiding the text will make the text **very** big on the screen. Is this really what you want?

Comment: if remove opacity it's not working why

Comment: Did you check my demo below?

Comment: I think OP wants the text not to fade out, but instead animate from the left and grow/shrink at the same time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

HTML

```
  <ul>
    <li><p>Text effect</p></li>
    <li><p>Text effect</p></li>
  </ul>
```

Css

```
ul li{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li p {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(10);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover p{
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.1s;
}
```

Try here http://jsbin.com/xohimubeso/edit?html,css,output

Comment: no I don't have to hide the text the text would be shown and li width:100%

Comment: Can't understand very well what you want to do, but this version should fit http://jsbin.com/bocokajufa/3/edit?html,css,output

Comment: wow, you couldn't just remove the `opacity` yourself? It's literally just removing that one line...

Answer (score 1):

Using `transform: scale()` like you did is a good way to implement this. However, you'll want to reset the scale to it's normal value when `:hover`.

Since `li` have by default `display: list-item` they take up 100% of the available width. As such, doing the zooming on the center of the `li` when the text is aligned to the left will make the text disappear. Wrap your text in a `span` that has `display: inline-block` in order to zoom in on the center of the text instead.

Also, the website you linked has the text fade in/out as well. Add `opacity: 0` to your `span` to make it invisible, and then have it transition to `opacity: 1` on `:hover` to achieve this fade in/out effect.

Also `transform: translateY(100px)` is probably not needed, nor is the duplicate `transition` property inside your `:hover`.

#### Demo 1 - no `opacity`, no box, animate from left

```css
ul li {
  background: lightgrey;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
ul li span {
  position: relative;
  left: -100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  transform: scale(10);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover span {
  left: 0;
  transform: scale(1);
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Text effect</span></li>
  <li><span>Text effect</span></li>
  <li><span>Text effect</span></li>
  <li><span>Text effect</span></li>
</ul>
```

#### Demo 2 - with `opacity`, box. As shown in attached link

```css
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  background: #FAEBD9;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
ul li span {
  font-size: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(10);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0.2s;
}
ul li:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Text effect</span></li>
  <li><span>Text effect</span></li>
  <li><span>Text effect</span></li>
  <li><span>Text effect</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following:

```html
<style>
#test-text:hover {
font-size: 20px;
}


</style>

<body>
<p id=test-text>TEST</p>
</body>
```